# can't create an invoice using JSON API (but XML works OK)

Tags: json, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I can create a new invoice using XML V3 QBO API:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
       <Line>
            <Description>Installation labor</Description>
            <Amount>420.00</Amount>
            <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SalesItemLineDetail>
                <ItemRef>1</ItemRef>
            </SalesItemLineDetail>
        </Line>
      <CustomerRef>58</CustomerRef>
</Invoice>
```

But I can't perform the same opeartion using JSON API. The JSON payload is:

```
{
  "Line": [
    {
      "Amount": 100.00,
      "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
      "SalesItemLineDetail": {
        "ItemRef": {
          "value": "1",
          "name": "Services"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "CustomerRef": {
    "value": "58"
  }
}
```

The JSON example returns the following error:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.","code":"10000"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2015-11-26T06:09:56.540-08:00"}
```

I'm performing both operations using Intuit's developer console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the content-type to JSON on API explorer when you test the Invoice json request

Comment: JSON content-type is selected. Please note that error message is a JSON output. For XML content-type error messages are displayed as XML output.

Comment: No, I meant change the content-type header field's text to application/json.

Comment: Thanks ! I can create a new invoice now as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Intuit's developer console, but in your xml you have an object called "Invoice", which isn't specifically present int the JSON object, perhaps: `{"Invoice": {"Line":{...}}}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but unfortunately the same error occurs.